# VBA - Create object to redirect "Write" method

Tags: vba, class, object

Right now I have an module where I call an object with the "write" method.

I do this 500 places around in the code, and now I need to support 2 objects instead of only 1 - But I will only write to one of them depending on an variable state

So originally I would have to write

```
If var = 1 Then
 Module1.Obj1.Write("some_data")
Else If var = 0 Then
 Module1.Obj2.Write("some_other_data")
End If
```

How do I create an object that can redirect the data based on an variable so I can write like:

```
Module1.ObjX.Write("data_here")
```

And down in the ObjX it reads "var" and if var = 1  then writes to Obj1 or if var = 0 write to Obj2

```
'if var = 1 then 
Module1.Obj1.Write("data")
else if var = 0 then
Module1.Obj2.Write("data")
```

It would make the code easier to understand and save a lot of work :S

Comment: Create function `ObjWrite()` in module and call that function; inside function decide, what to do.

Comment: Is `var` a global?

Comment: @NickSlash Yes,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard way of doing what you want is to create a dictionary of key value pairs.  The key is the value that selects which object you need to use to write and the value associated with the Key is the object you will use.  The code below uses a scripting.dictionary to achieve this.

At the module Level

```
Public myWriter as Scripting.Dictionary
```

In an initialisation subroutine

```
Set myWriter = New Scripting.Dictionary
with myWriter

    .Add 1,Obj1
    .Add 0.Obj2
    .Add 3.Obj3
    ' etc

End With
```

To call the approprite write function you can now just use

```
myWriter.Item(var).Write(DataValue)
```

'

Answer (score 1):

Pass the object by reference into a write function instead:

```vb
Sub WriteData(ByRef obj, ByVal data)
    'Write the data using the object here
End Sub

WriteData(Obj1, "data")
WriteData(Obj2, "data")
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the value of writervar before you call write object

Since writervar is global you can edit the value anywhere in your code.

```
Public writervar as Integer ' global scope
Public Sub WriteObj(Data)
Select Case writervar
Case 0
    ' do stuff
Case 1
    ' do stuff
Case Else
    ' error
End Select
End Sub
```